# Installing RVM: "Requirements installation failed with status: 1."

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

Here is the last thing I saw before the command prompt:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
About to install Homebrew, press `Enter` for default installation in `/usr/local`,
type new path if you wish custom Homebrew installation (the path needs to be writable for user)
: Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I don't think it made it to the point that I could press Enter

Comment: Since it stopped at the Homebrew installation, did you try installing Homebrew separately? Or perhaps you have a broken previous Homebrew installation?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I have homebrew; I've tried using some homebrew commands but none of them did anything "command not found"

Comment: OK, then go over to the Homebrew website at this URL: http://brew.sh/#install and do what the "Install Homebrew" part tells you to do.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this particular "status: 1" error (I know a number of people have received this, but it seems for different reasons)... I can confirm depa's comment and will add to it to create an answer to the question:

I just had to install Homebrew myself using the command from [brew.sh](http://brew.sh/):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then when I ran the RVM install command again it worked fine.

It seems RVM had a problem installing Homebrew on my machine for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for this. The rvm homepage was totally unhelpful in this matter. I am trying to update ruby on an oldish Mac and IMO this procedure is one of the worst experiences I've had in a long time. What is homebrew? Why do I need it? I love Ruby as a language but this amount of faffing about is beyond a joke. </rant>

Comment: That was super easy. Thanks for saving me from hours of yelling at the terminal.

Comment: getting curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

Answer (score 4):

Just ran Drewdavid's command and received the following:

> Whoops, the Homebrew installer has moved! Please instead run:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

> Also, please ask wherever you got this link from to update it to the above.

Comment: also getting curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

Answer (score 3):

For people deploying on Amazon Server or on linux needs to use

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Followed by `brew install gcc` , then Restart your system(logout and log in) and then `rvm install ruby -version`

Answer (score 1):

I opened Xcode manually and OK'd the license agreement to get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode
and installed the latest Command line tools and retried the install and it worked.